# How do I rotate and skew an SVG rect "in-place"?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am playing with SVG and I am stumped by something.
I am trying to make the pink square into a diamond by using `skew` and `rotate`.
However I am getting strange behaviour that I cannot figure out how to overcome.

[image: svg circles]

Adding the `skew`, gets me the diamond effect I want, but then I need to rotate and reposition it so it lines up with the circles.

`<rect x="126" y="0" width="40" height="40"fill="pink" transform="skewY(10)" />`

[image: skewed]

However, when I apply rotation `transform="rotate(45)"` to the `rect`, it doesn't rotate "in-place", but rotates [I think] relative from the corner of the page.

`<rect x="126" y="0" width="40" height="40"fill="pink" transform="skewY(10)" />`

[image: circle svg rotation]

Does anyone know how I can freely rotate and skew this rectangle (in SVG and not CSS or anything) without it moving around so wildly and awkwardly ?

```html
    <h1>Shapes</h1>
    <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <circle cx="62" cy="20" r="20" fill="yellow" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <circle cx="104" cy="20" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <rect x="126" y="0" width="40" height="40"fill="pink"/>
    <circle cx="188" cy="20" r="20" fill="green" stroke="red" ></circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to use transform-origin and transform-box

```css
rect {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shapes</h1>
    <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <circle cx="62" cy="20" r="20" fill="yellow" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <circle cx="104" cy="20" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red" ></circle>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="126" y="0" width="40" height="40"fill="pink"/>
    <circle cx="188" cy="20" r="20" fill="green" stroke="red" ></circle>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I really would prefer avoiding CSS though, if possible

Comment: But the transform attribute is just a mapping to CSS so unless you just want to draw shapes at the origin that are black you're always using CSS. If you really don't want to do it this way, work out the shape's origin yourself and add it as the additional two parameters to the rotate.

Comment: But then it's not portable.. I'll always have to manually recalculate if I move or use the rect somewhere else

Comment: Precisely, that's why I suggested the solution I did. Using transforms rather that x, y to position the rect should increase portability.

Comment: @CodyBugstein you can embed that stylesheet inside an .svg if that's your concern.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <h1>Shapes</h1>
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red"></circle>
   <circle cx="63" cy="21" r="20" fill="yellow" stroke="red"></circle>
   <circle cx="105" cy="21" r="20" fill="blue" stroke="red"></circle>
   <rect x="154" y="0" width="40" height="40" fill="pink" transform="rotate(45, 154, 0)"/>
   <circle cx="203" cy="21" r="20" fill="green" stroke="red"></circle>
 </svg>
```

This can be done using `rotate`. For rotate

- First argument is the angle of rotation i.e. 45 degrees.
- Second argument is the x offset about which the `rect` is to be rotated and is calculated as follows:

```
x = (border_width_of_circle_1 * 2 + radius_of_circle_1 * 2) + (border_width_of_circle_2 * 2 + radius_of_circle_2 * 2) + (border_width_of_circle_3 * 2 + radius_of_circle_3 * 2) + 1/2 * diagonal_of_square
  = (2 + 40) + (2 + 40) + (2 + 40) + (1/2 * sqrt(40^2 + 40^2))
  = 42 + 42 + 42 + (1/2 * sqrt(3200))
  = (42 * 3) + (1/2 * 56)
  = 126 + 28 = 154
```

- Third argument is the y offset about which the `rect` is to be rotated, which in our case will be `0`.

Comment: How did you come up with values `154` and `0` ?

Comment: `y=0` is for the distance of the top corner of the diamond from the top axis

Comment: `x=154` involves a bit of calculation :P

Comment: `x = (border_width_of_circle_1 * 2 + radius_of_circle_1 * 2) + (border_width_of_circle_2 * 2 + radius_of_circle_2 * 2) + (border_width_of_circle_3 * 2 + radius_of_circle_3 * 2) + 1/2 * diagonal_of_square`

Comment: `x = (2 + 40) + (2 + 40) + (2 + 40) + (1/2 * sqrt(40^2 + 40^2))`

Comment: `x = 42 + 42 + 42 + (1/2 * sqrt(3200))`

Comment: `x = (42 * 3) + (1/2 * 56)`

Comment: `x = 126 + 28 = 154` @CodyBugstein

Comment: I suppose you can add this math into the answer, not in comments.
Btw, there is a problem with scaling it. When i add `scale(2)` it scales almost out of view

Comment: Added @CodyBugstein :)
Can you share the desired view you want?